# Build Mandrill 'to' array with PHP

Tags: php, arrays, api, mandrill

I want to send multiple emails with Mandrill, but can't figure out how to build up the 'to' array. From their [docs](https://mandrillapp.com/api/docs/messages.php.html) it looks like this (and it's working):

```
'from_name' => 'My Name',
'to' => array(
    array(
        'email' => 'first@example.com',
        'name' => 'First Recipient',
        'type' => 'to'
    ),
    array(
        'email' => 'second@example.com',
        'name' => 'Second Recipient',
        'type' => 'to'
    )
),
'headers' => array('Reply-To' => 'me@example.org'),
```

My PHP code is:

```
foreach ($users as $user) {
    $to[] = array(
        array(
            'email' => 'first@example.com',
            'name' => 'First Recipient',
            'type' => 'to'
        ),
        array(
            'email' => 'second@example.com',
            'name' => 'Second Recipient',
            'type' => 'to'
        )
}
```

But when I insert recipients with $to, there must be a problem.

```
'from_name' => 'My Name',
'to' => $to,
'headers' => array('Reply-To' => 'me@example.org'),
```

Mandrill doesn't send anything and the result is an empty array (which means, no email was sent). Both arrays look the same to me. Are they?

For reference, here is the complete code:

```
public function notifySubscribers() {

    // Get page
    $scheduledPage = $from_db_query;

    // $users = wire('users')->find('!login_start>=today, !login_end<=today, limit=999');
    // foreach($users as $u) {
    //  if ( $u->hasPermission('page-view', $scheduledPage) ) {
    //      $recipients[] = $u;
    //  }
    // }
    $to = array(
                array(
                    'email' => 'first@example.com',
                    'name' => 'First Recipient',
                    'type' => 'to'
                ),
                array(
                    'email' => 'second@example.com',
                    'name' => 'Second Recipient',
                    'type' => 'to'
                )
            );

    // Returns array with stats from mailing
    $dispatched = $this->dispatchMail($scheduledPage->title, $scheduledPage->body, $scheduledPage->files->first(), $to);

}



/**
 * Dispatches the email to be sent
 *
 * Create email and send one email to each subscriber
 */
function dispatchMail($subject, $pageBody, $file, $from, $recipients) {

    require_once 'lib/mandrill-api-php/src/Mandrill.php';

    try {
        $mandrill = new Mandrill('xxxxxxxxx');
        $template_name = 'e-mail-notification';
        $template_content = array(
            array(
                'name' => 'PREHADER',
                'content' => 'Neue Ausgabe'
            )
        );
        $message = array(
            // 'html' => 'HTML Content',
            // 'text' => 'Text Content',
            'subject' => $subject,
            'from_email' => 'john@example.com',
            'from_name' => 'John',
            'to' => $to,
            'headers' => array('Reply-To' => 'reply@example.com'),
            'important' => false,
            'track_opens' => null,
            'track_clicks' => null,
            'auto_text' => null,
            'auto_html' => null,
            'inline_css' => true,
            'url_strip_qs' => null,
            'preserve_recipients' => false,
            'view_content_link' => null,
            // 'bcc_address' => '',
            'tracking_domain' => null,
            'signing_domain' => null,
            'return_path_domain' => null,
            'merge' => true,
            'merge_language' => 'mailchimp',
            'global_merge_vars' => array(
                array(
                    'name' => 'SUBJECT',
                    'content' => 'News'
                ),
                array(
                    'name' => 'PREHEADER',
                    'content' => 'Message'
                ),
                array(
                    'name' => 'CURRENT_YEAR',
                    'content' => date('Y')
                )
            ),
            'merge_vars' => array(
                array(
                    'rcpt' => 'test1@example.com',
                    'vars' => array(
                        array(
                            'name' => 'merge2',
                            'content' => 'merge2 content'
                        )
                    )
                )
            ),
            //'tags' => array('password-resets'),
            'subaccount' => 'xxxxx',
            'google_analytics_domains' => array('example.com'),
            'google_analytics_campaign' => 'message.from_email@example.com',
            'metadata' => array('website' => 'www.example.com'),
            'recipient_metadata' => array(
                array(
                    'rcpt' => 'test@example.com',
                    'values' => array('user_id' => 123456)
                )
            ),
            'attachments' => array(
                array(
                    'type' => 'text/plain',
                    'name' => 'dateiname.txt',
                    'content' => 'ZXhhbXBsZSBmaWxl'
                )
            )/*,
            'images' => array(
                array(
                    'type' => 'image/png',
                    'name' => 'IMAGECID',
                    'content' => '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'
                )
            )*/
        );
        $async = true;
        $ip_pool = '';
        $send_at = null;
        $result = $mandrill->messages->sendTemplate($template_name, $template_content, $message, $async, $ip_pool, $send_at);
        print_r($result);
        $return = $result;
    } catch(Mandrill_Error $e) {
        // Mandrill errors are thrown as exceptions
        $return = 'A mandrill error occurred: ' . get_class($e) . ' - ' . $e->getMessage();
    }

}
```

Comment: Can you show the rest of the code? What you've pasted looks ok so far

Comment: I'm voting to put this question on hold because the original poster says they will try to resolve it without Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 3):

In your loop you are doing this:

```
$to[] = array(
    array(
        'email' => 'first@example.com',
        'name' => 'First Recipient',
        'type' => 'to'
    ),
 );
```

Remember that this means you are pushing everything onto the `$to` array. But here you are pushing a two-level array, which in fact you only want to push a single level:

```
$to[] = array(
    'email' => 'first@example.com',
    'name' => 'First Recipient',
    'type' => 'to',
 );
```

Mandrill can't make sense of what you are doing, since it sees this:

```
array(
    array(
        array(
            'email' => 'first@example.com',
            'name' => 'First Recipient',
            'type' => 'to'
        ),
    ),
    array(
        array(
            'email' => 'second@example.com',
            'name' => 'Second Recipient',
            'type' => 'to'
        )
    ),
)
```

That's one too many levels!

Comment: halfer, thanks! That is what I had before, but it didn't work

Comment: I'm afraid that "didn't/doesn't work" doesn't give me anything to respond to, @suntrop. (I'd advise you not to use that phrase here - we often say it is the least informative fault report possible!). Try using `print_r()` after the loop to show the structure before it gets passed to Mandrill, and edit it into your question.

Comment: Sorry, I'll try and resolve it. Anyhow, thanks for your help.

Comment: @suntrop, no, don't give up on your question. Now that you have resolved to get assistance, I am trying to help you write a question that contains sufficient information to solve it. The first step is showing us what your array looks like after your loop has finished. Please edit your question.

Comment: Are your recipients really `something@example.com`? They won't work, for obvious reasons (example.com is a test domain and probably doesn't have MX domain records).